# register device for django push notifications

Tags: django, push-notification

making a `django` app to send push notifications to gcm devices using `django push notifications`, but unable to register the device on my server.  Followed the docs on `python.org` and filled in all the necessary details in `settings.py`.  Is there any particular `url` where the registration from the device should be accessed?
All the places I have looked have tutorials for php and java.

Someone please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

`django-push-notifications` does not have urls. To be able to send push notification first you have to associate the device with a user:

```
device = GCMDevice(name=device_name, user=user, device_id=device_id, registration_id=device_registration_id)
device.save()
```

You can do this for example after a user has registered.

Then when you want you can send a push notification to the user like this:

```
devices = GCMDevice.objects.filter(user=user)
devices.send_message("Push notification message!")
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I have used the same "django-push-notifications" and I'm sending message with Django admin panel. But it is not sending the message. Why?and it says..."All messages were sent: id=0:1427892673907867%bf2b8gd834eb0007".

Comment: Please give me more details. How do you register the devices?
After registration does this return something? GCMDevice.objects.all()

Comment: Can you please how to get device_registration_id, where we can find it?

Comment: device_name, device_id, device_registration_id has to come from the mobile app.

Comment: `name (optional): A name for the device.

active (default True): A boolean that determines whether the device will be sent notifications.

user (optional): A foreign key to auth.User, if you wish to link the device to a specific user.

device_id (optional): A UUID for the device obtained from Android/iOS/Windows APIs, if you wish to uniquely identify it.

registration_id (required): The GCM registration id or the APNS token for the device.`

Check the documentation: https://github.com/jleclanche/django-push-notifications